# AngularJS: Remove slide in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using in [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) the [Bootstrap Carousel](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel). I deactivated the ngAnimate, using [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1350), and the Carousel works fine, but the issue is when is **removed** a slide the carousels looks like this for a moment:

[image: Carousel after adding or removing a slide]

- Anybody have the same issue?
- What is wrong in my code?
- Any solution?

I'm using the `carousel.view.html` using **ng-include**.

#### carousel.view.html

```
<div class="carousel-height">
           <carousel class="carouselSpot"  disable-animation="true" >
                <slide  class="imgSlide" style="height: 355px; background-color: black" active="zone.active" ng-repeat="zone in spot.zones">
                    <img data-ng-if="zone.image"  style="position: absolute; margin-top:-1px; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-right: -50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);max-height: 355px;" data-ng-src="uploads/spots/850x850/{{zone.image}}" />
                </slide>
            </carousel>
        </div>
```

**Remove element**

```
spot.zones.splice(index,1);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, I just tried adding slides on the demo page and saw the same issue. So I would vote there's a bug in the package.

Comment: do you think is a Bootstrap bug and not mine? Or maybe there are another way to remove a slide in the carousel?

Comment: Yes, I don't think it's your bug. I didn't give it a thorough look but I saw the bug when adding a slide on their demo site.